# e.stopImmediatePropagation is not a function

Tags: event-propagation

This error is 9lesson.info site EDITDELETEPAGE template is
So This error is EDIT and DELETE functions have. error name is

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation is not a function


$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".delete").live('click',function()
{
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var b=$(this).parent().parent();
var dataString = 'id='+ id;
if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!"))
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "delete_ajax.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(e)
{
b.hide();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
       });
return false;
}
});
```

how to add add button please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because you are using `.live()` to bind your events. From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/):

> Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of live events.

Depending on which version of jQuery you are using, simply changing the `live` event handler to `on` ([jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) may fix the problem.